# GCP instance ubuntu connection refused using ssh and terminal?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I was using digitalocean and want to try out gcp compute instance. I created an ubuntu instance, did `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` in my terminal and added onto the instance. Then I tried `ssh james@external ip` in my terminal (I'm using mac) but it just hang there.. then a min later, I got `Connection refused` error. What's wrong?

Comment: Did you create the user `james` on the instance? The normal method of connecting to a Google Cloud instance is via `gcloud compute ssh NAME-OF-INSTANCE --zone ZONE-NAME`

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous possible reasons for this, but mostly likely you're missing a firewall rule to allow connections from the outside:

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create default-allow-ssh --allow tcp:22
```

If this doesn't help, check out the [Troubleshooting SSH](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh) article in the GCP docs.

Answer (score 1):

First check your network can communicate to compute engine via simple ping command.

```
ping <GCE external IP>
```

or

```
telnet <GCE external IP> 22
```

If you getting request timed out then most probably firewall issue. go to [cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/firewalls) and create/update firewall rule under VPC section. search tcp:22 in firewalls section and edit/create firewall rule (add your IP ranges into source IP range section) for ssh connection.

refer: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/firewall-rules/create